# In Rails 6, setting belongs_to and required, but RSpec is still complaining about my not setting required

Tags: rspec, associations, ruby-on-rails-6, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 6.2, Ruby 2.7.5 and RSpec 3.10.1.  When testing an association, I’m getting a strange error…

```
  Expected Voyage to have a belongs_to association called user (and for the record to fail validation if :user is unset; i.e., either the association should have been defined with `required: true`, or there should be a presence validation on :user)
```

I’m confused about what this error means.  Below my model is

```
class Voyage < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
     belongs_to :user, required: true
```

And the spec is

```
describe Voyage, :type => :model do

  describe 'associations' do
    it { should belong_to :user }
```

Comment: Hello, I found an answer for that. Check this: [GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/1095)

Answer (score 0):

The Github link that [codescaptain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15904580/codescaptain) shared has the solution that worked for me. But, I also needed to set the associations as `required` or `optional` depending on situation:

```rb
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:model).required }

it { is_expected.to belong_to(:model).optional }
```